# How to change the names from list of proteins to their ID with a protein table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a protein list like the given in df1

```
df1 <- data.frame(   names = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen3"))
```

I need to change those names to their ID using a protein table, the way they are related is summarized in df2

```
df2 <- data.frame(   
Protein.name = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen3"),  
 Protein.product = c("id1", "id2" , "id3"))
```

So I finally get a list of the protein ID instead of the protein names, as in df3

```
 df3 <- data.frame(   ID = c("id1", "id2" , "id3"))
```

I've tried using the `cbind` command but in order for that to work both data frames should have the same number of rows which is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something as `left_join()` from `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = c("names" = "Protein.name"))
```

This piece of code gets protein names in `df1` and provides their IDs from `df2` in that order. As for `df3`, it's:

```
library(tidyverse)
df3 <- df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = c("names" = "Protein.name")) %>%
    select(ID = Protein.product)
```

(The last line with `select` renames the data frame column to `ID` to get desired output as you wanted.)

---

**Example:** (with changed order of `df1` items to check it work)

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(names = c("Gen3", "Gen1", "Gen2"))

df2 <- data.frame(   
    Protein.name = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen3"),  
    Protein.product = c("id1", "id2" , "id3")
)

df3 <- df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = c("names" = "Protein.name")) %>%
    select(ID = Protein.product)

df3
```

Result:

```
    ID
1  id3
2  id1
3  id2
```

Comment: Hi Petr, Thanks for your quick response, Im not gonna lie, because some columns names where identical, Im now a mess trying to understan your response, could you give it a second look now that I've updated the columns names? Sorry for this newbie mistakes

Comment: @JoseGraciaRodriguez Hi Jose, I tried to update this piece of code so that fits your new column names. Let me know if it fits!

Comment: Hi again @peter, since I have to wait 90 minutes to post another question perhaps you can help me again I have a gene list like this

df1 <- data.frame(names = c("Gen1", "MULTISPECIES: Gen2", "Gen3", "MULTISPECIES: Gen4"))

I would like to get rid of the "MULTISPECIES:" so I end up with a list like

df2 <- data.frame(names = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen3", "Gen4"))
Sorry for all the trouble

Comment: @JoseGraciaRodriguez Hi Jose, you can probably replace the `names` column in `df1` by running: `df1$names <- gsub("MULTISPECIES: ", "", df1$names)` . Let me know if it works!

Comment: It does!! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JoseGraciaRodriguez Great! Thanks for your feed back, I'm glad it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
inner_join(df1,df2,by=c("name"="gene")) %>% select(name = name.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
out <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'name', by.y = 'gene')
```

---

Or with `match`

```
data.frame(name = df2$name[match(df1$name, df2$gene)])
```

Comment: I very like `base R` solutions! Your code needs to pick and rename the second column to get the desired result. But, however, according to `microbenchmark` it's pretty much faster than `tidyverse` solution...!

Comment: @PetrKajzar I think the tidyverse solutions are not meant for sole purpose of efficiency.  It is just more convenient way to express and as there are lots of functions to make it easier to express, there would be some baggage with loading different functions

Answer (score 1):

In `Base-R`

```
df1$names <- sapply(df1$names, function(x) df2$Protein.product[df2$Protein.name %in% x])

> df1
  names
1   id1
2   id2
3   id3
```